# On every single kernel update, I need to reinstall the NVidia driver and Unity is broken

Tags: unity, nvidia, 14.10

Every time I do a kernel update (with the regular standard update manager in Ubuntu 14.10), Unity breaks completely.
I need to reinstall the Nvidia drivers and I need to manually repair Unity.  If I don't repair Unity, users just see an empty desktop - there's lot's of posts about that.

It was a bit better when I was using Lubuntu (which I installed for that reason), on Lubuntu I just needed to reinstall the NVidia drivers.

This is so annoying it will push me off Ubuntu completely.  I've never liked Unity that much (although on my other machines, it's now workable) , but it is just so unstable .  How is it acceptable that repairing Unity is a regular task on a desktop (also see all the other posts on the subject) ?
The other problem is obviously with the Nvidia drivers ... never again I'll get a machine with Nvidia graphic cards ...

But anyway, does anybody have hints/tips how I can work with this ?  The big issue is that sometimes, other people need to use the PC and then it's unusable, so I have to fix it, which is a bit difficult for me most of the time since I'm rarely at home.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Please explain how you installed the NVidia drivers. Click [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/589190/edit) below your question and add the information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging around a bit for you... I found that version 340.65 the latest update via the Ubuntu repo claims to have fixed all of these bugs... Wouldn't hurt to give it a shot...

[How to install latest nvidia drivers Ubuntu ppa](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/12/install-nvidia-340-65-ubuntu-1504/)

Comment: OK , that works fine for me.  I don't know why I didn't do that to begin with ...

Answer (score 0):

**Ubuntu 14.10 is not LTS and many packages come from Debians non-stable branch. I recommend going back to 14.04 LTS for stable upgrades**

*If you want to stick with 14.10 I suggest the following before each upgrade...*

Try removing all previous nvidia drivers first `sudo apt-get -purge nvidia`

Remove current nvidia driver `sudo apt-get remove nvidia-340`

**After upgrading then re-install the nvidia driver.**

Comment: Same thing happend on 14.04 .  I'm not using the nvidia driver from the Ubuntu repositories, I'm using the binary driver from nvidia.  The nvidia driver on the Ubuntu repositories does not work at all for me.

Comment: System details? What branch version are you using? If you are using the latest long lived branch you may have to fall back to an earlier branch.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem for years! I was manually reinstalling nvidia drivers after each upgrade. Finally I discovered the problem can stem from `dkms`, which is supposed to rebuild modules upon installation of a new kernel.

Try: `dkms status`

For me, this threw an error message, which helped me realize the source of the problem:

```
Error! Could not locate dkms.conf file.
File: /var/lib/dkms/anbox-modules-ashmem/8~zesty1/source/dkms.conf does not exist.
```

In my case, I had some leftover files in `/var/lib/dkms/` that should have been removed when I uninstalled Anbox. So I manually removed those (`sudo rm -rf /var/lib/dkms/anbox-modules-ashmem`) and afterward `dkms status` worked, and kernel upgrades automatically compiled new nvidia drivers.

You may similarly have some bad files in `/var/lib/dkms/` (either from Anbox or some other program) that prevent `dkms` from working normally.